# Flutter app taking POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission without specifying in the manifest

Tags: flutter, notifications, android-permissions

I am working on a Flutter app. In this app, the notification permission is not required but I am seeing notification permission on my Android phone even though I didn't ask for POST_NOTIFICATIONS as you can see in my app's permission and below in my manifest I didn't write
.

[image]

[image]

Comment: is it happened on android 13?

Comment: Yes but below Android 13 it also shows notification permission in app and initially allows it even if I didn't specify it in the manifest.

Comment: Can you provide the screensort of your used plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are chances that libraries you are using are using this notification permission as when you app is build , all manifest files are merged so to overcome this issue you can try by adding this line to your own manifest

```
<uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"
     tools:node="remove" />
```

But one thing consider that there are chances that library which is using this permission may break down and create crashes so either find and remove that lib if it is not important or try above solution and check your app